# Determining normalizing constant of joint density function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let $T_x$ and $T_y$ be two random variables that desribe the remaining lifetimes of two persons, aged $x$ and $y$ respectively. The joint density of $T_x$ and $T_y$ is given by

$$f(s,t)=\begin{cases}C(50^2-(s-t)^2),& s,t \in [0,50]\\0, &\mathrm{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

($T_x$ and $T_y$ are *not* independent). $C>0$ is a normalizing constant.

How can I determine $C$?

Comment: Choose $C$ such that $f$ integrates to $1$. The computation involved here is very simple.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know it must equal $1$, then it is very simple indeed

Comment: Would you consider posting an answer and accept it yourself (self-answering is encouraged on the site), or deleting this question post to wrap it up? It seems that you have already got what you wanted here or elsewhere and have moved on.